# How get variable from View to Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to get a variable from a button to the Controller. I have a button 'Edit' and when I click it I want to send the number of the line to a controller in order to know what Driver needs Editing.

This my Controller:

```
 static  List<Drivers> Driver = new List<Drivers>();

    // GET: DriverTaxi
    public ActionResult List()
    {

        if (Driver.Count == 0)
        {
            Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 1, NumberLicens = "123456", FirstName = "Evgeny", LastName = "Ryvkin", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17" });
            Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 2, NumberLicens = "123457", FirstName = "Moshe", LastName = "Kohen", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17" });
            Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 3, NumberLicens = "123458", FirstName = "Dana", LastName = "Multy", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17" });
        }

        ViewBag.Drivers = Driver;
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult MyAction(int  id=0)
    {


       // int numberLine = Convert.ToInt32(lineDriver);//convert string to int
       for(int i = 0; i < Driver.Count; i++)
        {
            if(Driver[i].Line == id)
            {
                ViewBag.nl = Driver[i].NumberLicens;
                ViewBag.fn = Driver[i].FirstName;
                ViewBag.ln = Driver[i].LastName;
                ViewBag.phone = Driver[i].PhoneNumber;
                ViewBag.start = Driver[i].StartWork;
                ViewBag.eye = Driver[i].DateCheckEyes;
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The table sends the variable, but I can't receive in in Controller; I don't Understand why.

This is my View:

```
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Number Licens</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Start Work</th>
            <th>Date Cheking the Eyes</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (Drivers p in ViewBag.Drivers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@p.Line</td>
            <td>@p.NumberLicens</td>
            <td>@p.FirstName &nbsp; @p.LastName </td>
            <td>@p.PhoneNumber</td>
            <td>@p.StartWork</td>
            <td>@p.DateCheckEyes</td>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "DriverTaxi"))
            {
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="DriverName" value="hello" />
                <input type="submit" name="123" value="Edit" />
                @Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "DriverTaxi", new { id = p.Line })
            </td>
            }
   }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have not shown your view.

Comment: Why do you have a link inside your form? You view is not really making sense - are you wanting to submit the form to a `[HttpPost]` method or are you wanting to make a GET to the `MyAction()` method you have shown?

Comment: I wont to make a Get to the MyAction().

Comment: Your link needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "MyAction", new { id = p.Line })` - the 1st parameter is the text of the link and the 2nd is the named of the action (assuming both those methods are in the same controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view) will provide with the information you seek.

[EDIT: Didn't see the view code.]
Don't iterate through your list like that. If you have the index of the element you seek, you can use Driver.ElementAt(i). This will return the value at the given index. 
Also, maybe it's not a bad idea to use a model in your view. This will illimenate the need for all those viewBags you have.

```
@model List<Drivers>
```

when calling your view you can give your list as an argument then

```
return View(Driver);
```

and then when you iterate through your drivers you can just do:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <td>@item.Line</td>
   <td>@item.NumberLicens</td>
   // ...
}
```

As for the matter of your ActionLink, isn't the syntax as follows:

```
Html.ActionLink(article.Title, 
                "Item",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "Login",  // <-- Controller Name.
                new { article.ArticleID }, // <-- Route arguments.
                null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none. You need this value
                      //     otherwise you call the WRONG method ...
                      //     (refer to comments, below).
                )
```

Which would mean that you have your "MyAction" in the place where printed value is located, not where your actionmethod is, maybe this will work:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit","MyAction", "DriverTaxi", new { id = p.Line },null)
```

I'm not an expert whatsoever, so if my info is wrong, feel free to correct this.

Comment: That would add the `id` as a html attribute, not a route attribute

Comment: It needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("Edit","MyAction", "DriverTaxi", new { id = p.Line }, null)` if you specify the controller name

Comment: Stephen Muecke and Vandenberghe Willy, I want to say you BIG THANK YOU, because I need give some little project with mvc5,  if this project will be done, I will have a job, so again thank you, you are amazing!!!!